# If event is Enter Button or mouse click, do something

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search bar and I want the user to be able to call the handleSearch function when they click the search button or hit the enter key. The search button works fine but I can't for the life of me get it to work when the enter key is hit. Help, please :)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { searchBlogs, setSearchQuery } from '../../actions/searchBlogsAction';

function SearchComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
  };

  // Search blogs and redirect to the search results page
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 || e == ??) {
      e.preventDefault();
      history.push('/search-results');
      dispatch(setSearchQuery(searchInput));
      dispatch(searchBlogs(searchInput));
      setSearchInput('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form inline>
      <FormControl
        type="text"
        size="sm"
        placeholder="Search"
        className="mr-sm-2"
        onChange={inputHandler}
        value={searchInput}
        onKeyPress={handleSearch}
      />
      <Button size="sm" variant="outline-secondary" onClick={handleSearch}>
        Search
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default SearchComponent;
```

Comment: This should throw a SyntaxError. `if (e.keyCode === 13 || e == ??)`. You can't use `?` like this.

Comment: @HåkenLid I can't say with certitude, but I think he just meant to show `??` to ask *hey, what should I put here?...*

Comment: The thing is `??` is actually the new [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). It must have an operand on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [react-bootstrap docs regarding Form](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/), you can pass `onSubmit` callback to the `Form` component, like so:

```
- <Form inline>
+ <Form inline onSubmit={handleSearch}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
      <FormControl
        type="text"
        size="sm"
        placeholder="Search"
        className="mr-sm-2"
        onChange={inputHandler}
        value={searchInput}
        onKeyPress={event => event.key === "Enter" && handleSearch()}
      />
```

And the `handleSearch` function should just be:

```
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      history.push('/search-results');
      dispatch(setSearchQuery(searchInput));
      dispatch(searchBlogs(searchInput));
      setSearchInput('');
  }
```

Comment: Hey. I have tried this before and have no idea why it will not work. When I press the enter key, the page just refreshes. So it seems like it just does the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add an `onSubmit` event handler to the form instead.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { searchBlogs, setSearchQuery } from '../../actions/searchBlogsAction';

function SearchComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
  };

  // Search blogs and redirect to the search results page
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push('/search-results');
    dispatch(setSearchQuery(searchInput));
    dispatch(searchBlogs(searchInput));
    setSearchInput('');
  };

  return (
    <Form inline onSubmit={handleSearch}>
      <FormControl
        type="text"
        size="sm"
        placeholder="Search"
        className="mr-sm-2"
        onChange={inputHandler}
        value={searchInput}
      />
      <Button type="submit" size="sm" variant="outline-secondary">
        Search
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default SearchComponent;
```

Clicking the submit button in a form will trigger the submit event as will hitting the enter key.

Comment: Hmmm, I could be wrong, but I think you got downvoted because the `handleSearch` function will get triggered on every keypress, as in ANY key, not just enter. Since there is nothing in `handleSearch` to filter the specific key that got pressed, all the code in the function will run each time the input is updated.

Comment: but my code doesn't attach handleSearch to `onChange` it attaches it to `onSubmit` for the form, which should only trigger when the form is submitted by hitting the enter key

Comment: This is the problematic part: `onKeyPress={handleSearch}`

Comment: I put this Sandbox together for you to demonstrate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-glade-sk5s8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ah, definitely, I see the issue. Just didn't see that was there :sweat-smile: that for sure would create a problem!